# Ruby/Rails organizing and loading constants for an entire module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question may just be for Ruby, but it was from working on a Rails that spurred me asking this question.

Suppose I am creating a new `module` so that I can better organize correlated/coupled code. Let's call this module `amazing_feature` and all of it's classes/submodules are located in the `app/services` directory. So according to code loading principles, the entire module should be in the `app/services/amazing_feature` directory in order to be loaded properly.

Let's say that I have two classes for this module:

```rb
# app/services/amazing_feature/thing_one.rb
module AmazingFeature
  class ThingOne
    ...
  end
end

# app/services/amazing_feature/thing_two.rb
module AmazingFeature
  module ThingTwo
    ...
  end
end
```

There are some constants that I would like to be available for all of the classes/submodules within `module AmazingFeature`, as well as being available from the `AmazingModule` namespace for any external code (eg, other controllers and models, in the Rails point of view). For example, if I want to define `MY_CONSTANT = 1`, then it would be accessible as just `MY_CONSTANT` within the module and as `AmazingFeature::MY_CONSTANT` from outside the module.

So the question is, how can I actually accomplish this in Ruby or Rails? There are thoughts that I've had, approaches that think may work, or approaches that I have seen elsewhere, such as other SOF posts:

- Make a file directly in `app/services` for the module that associate the constants directly to the module. I don't prefer this approach because it feels weird putting a file coupled to the module outside of its subdirectory.

```rb
# app/services/amazing_feature.rb
module AmazingFeature
  MY_CONSTANT = 1
end
```

- Load the constants globally as a Rails initializer (ie, in `config/initializers`). I also have the same dislike for this approach as above.
- Create a `Constants` module in the subdirectory so that the constants are colocated with all other code for the module. I just don't know how to properly associate these constants to the parent module, so there is a missing piece in this code example.

```rb
# app/services/amazing_feature/constants.rb
module AmazingFeature
  module Constants
    MY_CONSTANT = 1
  end
end

# Now what??? :(
```

- Some other approach? I'm at a loss here.

Thank you.

Comment: have you seen the rails guide on autoloading code? You want to read this thoroughly as it helps in many respects... https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want of course, but take some inspiration from popular gems:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record.rb
- https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri.rb
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb

It is normal to rely on Ruby autoloaders to map the names of your constants (`AmazingFeature`) to file names that contain those constants. So `AmazingFeature` could map to `load/path/amazing_feature.rb` and `AmazingFeature::Greatness` could map to `load/path/amazing_feature/greatness.rb`.

I'd advise doing this and pretty soon it won't feel weird :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea:

```rb
# app/services/amazing_feature/constants.rb
module AmazingFeature
  module Constants
    MY_CONSTANT = 1
  end
  include AmazingFeature::Constants
end

module AmazingModule
 include AmazingFeature::Constants
end

# Then
AmazingFeature::MY_CONSTANT # => 1
AmazingModule::MY_CONSTANT # => 1
```